# Hide/Show div based on more then data attributes value in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div like

```
<div class="item" id="unique_id" data_brand_id="100" data_category_id="10" data_is_promo="1"> </div>
<div class="item" id="unique_id" data_brand_id="100" data_category_id="10" data_is_promo="1"> </div>
<div class="item" id="unique_id" data_brand_id="101" data_category_id="11" data_is_promo="2"> </div>
<div class="item" id="unique_id" data_brand_id="101" data_category_id="11" data_is_promo="2"> </div>
```

Here i can show/hide based on attribute value  like

```
$('[data_brand_id="100"]').attr('style', 'display:none;');
$('[data_category_id="10"]').attr('style', 'display:none;'); 
same for attr data_is_promo
```

but it like OR condition. it's showing all DIV those have brand id OR category ID.

But I want to hide/show based on all attr using AND condition.
Show/Hide all div those have data_brand_id = 100 AND data_category_id == 10 AND data_is_promo == 1 and hide/show rest DIV.

I have brand_id and category_id in java-script array.

How to apply AND condition.

Comment: You have multiple items with the same id="tr_3990". ids have to be unique.

Comment: @matthias_h my bad. que updated. Yes ID is unique for every DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) that *matches elements that match all of the specified attribute filters.*:

```js
$('[data_brand_id="100"][data_category_id="10"][data_is_promo="1"]').attr('style', 'display:none;');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="100" data_category_id="10" data_is_promo="1"> 111</div>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="100" data_category_id="10" data_is_promo="1">2222 </div>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="101" data_category_id="11" data_is_promo="2">33333 </div>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="101" data_category_id="11" data_is_promo="2"> 4444</div>
```

**Please Note:** It is better to use jQuery's [**`.css()`**](https://api.jquery.com/css/) when working with style:

```js
$('[data_brand_id="100"][data_category_id="10"][data_is_promo="1"]').css({'display': 'none'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="100" data_category_id="10" data_is_promo="1"> 111</div>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="100" data_category_id="10" data_is_promo="1">2222 </div>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="101" data_category_id="11" data_is_promo="2">33333 </div>
<div class="item" id="tr_3990" data_brand_id="101" data_category_id="11" data_is_promo="2"> 4444</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate all the selectors together.

```
$('[data_brand_id="100"][data_category_id="10"]').style('display', 'none;');
```

Refer : [Multiple Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)